# As keyword SQL VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I was looking at SQL statement for an example database which went something like this'

```
SELECT INDEX, SUM AS Total FROM INVD WHERE INV=[Forms]![ENTRY].[INV]
```

What does AS mean on the code above?

Also is me.Entry same as [Forms]![ENTRY]

Comment: Did you run it with and without to see? It's an "alias". It "renames" the column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key word `AS` indcates, that you want to use an alias for your column name.

```
SELECT Sales FROM Table1 'The column name in the output query will be Sales

SELECT Sales As Money FROM Table1 'The column name in the output query will be Money
```

To your second question it is not the same. If `Form1` is the active form and you use `me.ID` it will be the same like `Form1!ID`. Same when `Form2` is the active form and you use `me.ID` it will be `Form2!ID`. So `.me` refers always to the active form. But when you use `Forms!Form2!ID` it will always look for `Form2` even when `Form1` is the active form.